# Select inside a select query MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello! I have a query that needs to output screens data.
Each screens has 4 booths to be shown. I need a query with one result (because I just have one screen) And has 4 booths in it (coz I assigned 4 booths)

**Here's my query:**

```
$result = DB::select("
    SELECT
        `A`.`scr_name`,
        `A`.`mission_id`,
        `B`.`booth_id`,
        `E`.`name`
    FROM `tbl_screen` `A`
    LEFT JOIN
        `tbl_screen_booths` `B`
    ON `B`.`screen_id` = `A`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN
        `tbl_service_booths` `C`
    ON `B`.`booth_id` = `C`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN
        `tbl_missions_services` `D`
    ON `C`.`mission_services_id` = `D`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN
        `tbl_services` `E`
    ON `D`.`service_id` = `E`.`id`
    WHERE `A`.`mission_id` = $mission_id
    GROUP BY
        `B`.`booth_id`;
");

return $result;
```

I want something like this:

```
"scr_name": "Test Screen",
"mission_id": 2,
"name": "booth1", //index[0]
"name": "booth2", //index[1]
"name": "booth3", //index[2]
"name": "booth4" //index[4]
```

My query returns something like this:

```
[
{
"scr_name": "Test Screen",
"mission_id": 2,
"booth_id": 7,
"name": "booth1"
},
{
"scr_name": "Test Screen",
"mission_id": 2,
"booth_id": 9,
"name": "booth2"
},
{
"scr_name": "Test Screen",
"mission_id": 2,
"booth_id": 10,
"name": "booth3"
},
{
"scr_name": "Test Screen",
"mission_id": 2,
"booth_id": 11,
"name": "booth4"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the result is okay.. just need a little iterate to get the value..

```
$data['scr_name'] = $result[0]->scr_name;
$data['mission_id'] = $result[0]-> mission_id;

foreach($result as $index => $item) {
     $data['name'.($index+1)] => $item->name;
}
```

result:

```
"scr_name": "Test Screen",
"mission_id": 2,
"name1": "booth1", //index[0]
"name2": "booth2", //index[1]
"name3": "booth3", //index[2]
"name4": "booth4" //index[4]
```

array key cant have same key name

Comment: however this is doesn't fit, if I have multiple screens, as it'll return multiple results.

Comment: then you need to iterate the data.. put some logic.. then produce output.. this is just sample from your data